# I'm trying to show PDF through url in webview android in java. Only Image is showing through url but not PDF

Tags: android, android-webview

```
//        file_name = "07092022114344-java_tutorial.pdf";
    file_name = "07092022114344-1662530603380.jpg";
    dialog_attach_expense_info = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
    binding.expenseAttach.setText(file_name);
    binding.expenseAttach.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        openDialogShowDownloadImagePDF();
    });
```

> the above code is basically in the onCreate method of the main activity

```
private void openDialogShowDownloadImagePDF() {

    dialogBinding = DialogImagePdfBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());

    dialog_attach_expense_info.setContentView(dialogBinding.getRoot());
    dialog_attach_expense_info.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    dialog_attach_expense_info.setCancelable(false);
    dialog_attach_expense_info.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.animation;
    // set background transparent
    dialog_attach_expense_info.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

    //TODO: image view code to view image from url (PDF/Image)
    dialogBinding.webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    dialogBinding.webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
//        dialogBinding.webView.loadUrl("url" + file_name);
        dialogBinding.webView.loadUrl("url" + file_name);

        dialogBinding.btnCloseDialog.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            dialog_attach_expense_info.dismiss();
        });
        dialogBinding.btnDownloadDialog.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            //TODO: download event

        });

        dialog_attach_expense_info.show();
    }
```

> Here in the above the URL is working well in chrome. But the URL that consists of .pdf is not showing up in the webview any ideas where this code lacks

Comment: A WebView cannot display a pdf document.

Comment: then is it possible with image view?

Comment: ImageView is for images dont you think?

Comment: then how can I show a pdf and in what way?

Comment: Download the beast. Then let the user choose a pdf reader app by starting an intent for ACTION_VIEW.

Comment: but client requirement is to show image/pdf then to download if needed

Comment: The client (and you) should realise that one cannot show a pdf document before it is downloaded.

Comment: Oh, I got a pdf viewer ready to work on it... Thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score 2):

I did some research and got this as the solution for my requirement for an in-app pdf viewer https://github.com/ShreeOcean/pdfViewerHorizontal hopefully this will help others, the only thing is that it's restricted up to a few pages not the total number of pages.